# Plone: Editing name of portlets

Tags: plone

On the homepage of the website, there is one "News" portlet on the left side. I want to change the title of this portlet to "News and Events". Because when I click on Manage Portlets >> News there is no where to edit the name of this portlet. Is doing this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to ZMI -> portal_view_customization -> news.pt (this is the template for the news portlet) -> customize and change the title, removing the i18n tag for translation and rolling your own translation.

Answer (score 6):

The News Portlet has a static "translated" title. It also shows only NewsItems. 
You can configure the workflow state and the number of NewsItems.

Workaround:

You can create and configure (Type: NewsItem / Sort on: Effective date) a `Collection`.
Then add a collection portlet.
Set the Portlet header to "News and Events" and use the collection you created as "Target collection". Also enable "Show dates".